# Where to ask questions with a historical element of a tool?

Tags: discussion, scope

I currently have a question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275674/rsyslogd-as-a-session-leader) that has a historical element to it. While the majority of the question asks about the behaviour as it exists today, there is this sentence:

> The book clearly wants to make a point of why it's different, so if anyone knows why historically it didn't used to be a session leader, and why it is now, that'd be excellent.

I do wonder if this question is appropriate for stack overflow. I wouldn't normally ask questions with a historical element, but I feel in this case it is fairly essential to the question. Despite requiring some history, I don't think the question is opinion based and I'm sure it has a concrete answer out there. Indeed, some of the best answers on this site delve into a bit of history first.

I'd love to hear some insight about this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the history of any language or tool commonly used by programmers (actually, it's commonly used, but it's as common as saying that Linux is commonly used by programmers).

Comment: I've received a great answer on the original SO question now, in which they delved into the source code from a few years back, so in the end it had both programming and historical elements.

Comment: [Stephane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) probably found your question through following the link on your meta.UL question. He tends to answer more on UL than SO.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bad question, but Stack Overflow isn't the right audience for it.  [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *appears* to tacitly allow this kind of question...

> UNIX C API and System Interfaces ( within reason )

...although my recommendation would be to post this sort of question on their Meta and see if they agree.

Comment: Thanks heaps, do you think I should close to SO question and re-ask on Unix.SE? Or is a migration preferable? And also to ask this meta question on the Unix meta.

Comment: It's tricky; we have a direct migration path to Unix & Linux ourselves, but it'd be wise to pose the question (with a link) on their Meta first.

Comment: Sorry I'm getting a bit confused about which questions should be moved or re-asked and where, do you think you could clarify which course of action I should take?

Comment: Post the question on Meta Unix and Linux with a link to your question on Stack Overflow.  If you can sense some kind of consensus in that it'd be on-topic there, then you can flag it for migration to Unix and Linux.  I'll personally abstain from action until you can get some kind of consensus.

Comment: Legend, I've done so [here](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4285/where-to-ask-questions-with-a-historical-element).

Comment: @DanielPorteous  err... you're now asking on their meta if the question is fit for Stack Overflow. I can't imagine that was your intention.

Comment: My main concern wasn't whether the question is better on SO or Unix.SE, but whether the historical aspects are welcome. I did mention at the start of the question that a migration was being considered, perhaps I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: I've received confirmation that it's the right thing to do, should be good to go on the migration.